# homopolymer filter for repeats of 2 or more bases

Tags: python, regex

I have homopolymers which are repeats like ACACAC, GTGT etc.

How can I look for such patterns using regex in python. Eg.

```
seq = 'ACCTTAAAGG'
x = [(m.group(), m.start()) for m in re.finditer(r'([ACGT])\1{2,}', seq) if len(m.group()) > 3]
```

looks for repeats of A or T or G or C of length > 3.

Can you suggest how I can use regular expressions for repeats of the type AT, CG, AG, ...etc.

Comment: do you want your regex to match `ACACAC`,  `CGCGCG` or what?

Comment: My regex should match repeats of AC, TG, CG etc. if they occur more than 3 times consecutively in the sequnce. Eg. the sequence TGCTACACACAC should be flagged but not TGTCACACGGT.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex `(AC){3,}|(AG){3,}|(GC){3,}|(GT){3,}`

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'ACACACCTTAACGCGCGAGGCGCGCGC'
>>> pat = re.compile(r'(AC){3,}|(AG){3,}|(GC){3,}|(GT){3,}')
>>> [(m.group(), m.start()) for m in re.finditer(pat, s)]
[('ACACAC', 0), ('GCGCGCGC', 19)]
```